# Use HTML and CSS in Android app for design

Tags: android, html, css

Can I use HTML and CSS code in Android app for design?

I mean make a search box by HTML not make an app with HTML and CSS.

Edit : Meant, could HTML be used inside an android app to beatify components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for doing the same in just one activity in a some existing android application, then you should go for [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

If you just want to discard the boring Edit text there is an option:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/user"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I just want make search box or make a button because textbox or plane box of eclipse is so ugly...

Comment: so basically you want to make it look pretty!             try and search how to implement   `<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, there are several frameworks that may help you. My personal opinion is that apps that have been created this way will never be able to be as perfectly integrated and fine tuned as an app created with Androids own layout and design techniques.

Some options are:

- [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)
- [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There have some framesworks
check it out:

```
http://codecondo.com/top-12-frameworks-for-android-app-development/
```